# Use Firebase Hosting for Notifications

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-hosting

I am newbie to Firebase Hosting and Cloud Messaging but I think this can solve my problems with notifications. At the moment my Android 'book'-application uses a listener to check if there is a new book added or the status of interesting books for the respective user has changed. Moreover the listener actually checks if there is a new chatmessage for a loaned book. Because of the download quantity I would like to change this now!
My database structure looks like this:

```
/ 
+ chats
    + 123abc    // id of a book
        + 456def    // id of a message
            - messagetext: "Hello!"
            - messagetime:1502569166935
            - messageuserid: 789ghi
        + 654fed    // id of another message
            - messagetext....


+ books
    + 123abc    // id of a book (for this book is the message above)
        - bookname: "Firebase Tutorial"
        - uid: "321uvw"    // this user is interested in the book
        - status: "yes"
```

How can I achieve that the a notification will be send to the respective user when a chatmessage is new for a book he is interested in? And how can I notify the user when a new book was created or a the status of an existing book has changed where his user-id ("uid") is used?
I hope you can help me! Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you have any existing code that you could share?

Answer (score 1):

You should look into Firebase Cloud Functions. Using them you can attach a listener for write/update/etc on the nodes you are interested in. Then trigger a notification anyway you want in response to the trigger. See: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/